# How can I delete the consent popup from wordpress files?

Tags: wordpress, selenium-webdriver, popup, gdprconsentform

[image: Wordpress site]

I recently took administration of the website and I cannot find out how to delete the following consent popup at the screenshot of this url: https://ibb.co/CWYwMh8. There is no plugin and I cannot find any tag at the header or footer. I checked at functions as well.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to delete it.

Regards,
Labros

I tried to locate the code with the help of the plugin: `WP String Locator`, but cannot find it.

Comment: I searched for `fc-dialog-container` and found that this might be a Google solution available to Adsense customers to address GDPR Cookie Consent [source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/242846102/poor-cls-score-on-google-search-console-caused-by-funding-choices-message?hl=en). Check if you can deactivate it in your Google Adsense account. Your GA account is most likely linked to your site via `<script>` tags in your `header.php` file, or a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code below to click on <kbd>Consent</kbd> button using Python Selenium.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://nikosantoniadis.tv/')

# Create a wait object with 10s wait time
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

# Locate the consent button and click on it
consent_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='fc-button fc-cta-consent fc-primary-button']")))
consent_btn.click()
time.sleep(10)
```